# How to tile a Sprite Node's Texture?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, textures, tiling

Using SpriteKit, how would I tile a SKTexture that repeats itself horizontally to fill the width of the SKSpriteNode? This is what I have so far - only stretches the texture.

```
var header = SKSpriteNode()
let headerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "inGameHeader-1.png")
header = SKSpriteNode(texture: headerTexture)
header.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)-39)
header.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)
header.size.height = 150
header.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 1)
addChild(header)
```

Comment: I think there is no simple way currently to tile a texture, but you can generate many sprites in single drawing pass. Which gives you similar result...

Comment: hmm, how would i go about doing that? All i really need to do is repeat a 1px width gradient to fill a header background. I just figured that'd be more efficient than having a 600px width gradient that's just the 1px repeated

Comment: As I said there is no currently simple way to do this, but you don't have to worry about that, Spritekit has it's way to optimize things : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH7-SW7

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution :   Send your image to this function, with the size of the sprite, followed by the size of the tile. This will return a tiled SKTexture.

```
-(SKTexture *)tiledTextureImage:(UIImage *)image ForSize:(CGSize)size tileSize:(CGSize)tileSize{

// First we create a new size based on the longest side of your rect
int targetDimension = (int)fmax(size.width,size.height);
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(targetDimension, targetDimension);

// Create a CGImage from the input image and start a new image context.
struct CGImage *targetRef = image.CGImage;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Now we simply draw a tiled image
CGContextDrawTiledImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0,0, tileSize.width,tileSize.height), targetRef);
UIImage *tiledTexture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Finally create a texture and return it. 
return  [SKTexture textureWithImage:tiledTexture];
}
```

Comment: thanks, works ok but one problem with this is you are forcing the targetSize to a square based on max of height or width. while it fills the sprite, it actually 'over fills it, leaving extra tiles offscreen. i didn't need that extra baggage so i took out the first 2 lines and used the "size" i passed instead of targetSize.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a static function for Swift 3 and 4. Not using an extension as the SKTexture class doesn't actually have a designated initializer.

Note this won't be very performant. Best to preload the texture before use, or dive into the world of custom Shaders.

```
static func generateTiledTexture(size: CGSize, imageNamed imageName: String) -> SKTexture? {
    var texture: SKTexture?

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    if let image = UIImage(named: imageName), let cgImage = image.cgImage {
        context?.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height), byTiling: true)

        if let tiledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
            texture = SKTexture(image: tiledImage)
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return texture
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you know you can do this in UIButton or UIImageView by resizableImageWithCapInsets ,so ,Here is my solution :

```
-(SKTexture *)textureWithImage:(UIImage *)image tiledForSize:(CGSize)size withCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets{
//get resizable image
image =  [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:capInsets];
//redraw image to target size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width-1, size.height-1)];
[[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
//get target image
UIImage *ResultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// get texture
SKTexture * texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:ResultImage];
return texture;
}
```

Comment: This method is effective